# origin value and after sum after ROUND() is different

Tags: excel

I have a table with "ordered amount", "percentages", and "total sum". Note that "ordered amount" and "total sum" should be the same.

column F= sum of C:F

*rows 4,6,8,10 used `=round()`

[image]

As shown in the table(image), for some numbers, value in F is not the same as A when it should be. (e.g. A6(105) and F7(104), -1 after rounding).

Is there anyway to avoid this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it not obvious what is happening?  When you round you are throwing away everything after the decimal place (and possibly changing the tens digit).

Comment: Why do you think that the sum of a series of numbers should be the same as the sum of that same series of rounded numbers?

Comment: Sorry, I don't mean to say it should be, I need it to be. Take "344" as example, let's distribute 344 mobile phones over 4 areas (A, B, C, and D). Obviously I can't distribute 0.7 of a phone, so I would round it up as 1. By using '=round()', it returns a total of 345 thus I will be 1 phone short for distribution.

Answer (score 0):

If the sum of the decimal points adds up to > 5, your final rounded number will round up. If they add up to < 5, the final number will round down.

Consider this example:

```
10.5 + 5 = 15.5, which rounds to 16.
```

However

```
10 + 5 = 15
```

This is what is happening in your table.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the sum of rounded numbers to add up to the same as the sum of the numbers, in your example, you will need to NOT round, but rather subtract, one of the values.  I would suggest altering the largest value, as it would seem to have the least effect on the percentages, but that is a choice you can make.

To do that, with your data in row 8, for example you could do the following.

```
A9: =IF(B$8=MAX($B$8:$E$8),SUM($B$8:$E$8)-SUM(ROUND($B$8:$E$8,0))+ROUND(B$8,0),ROUND(B$8,0))
```

entered as an array formula with `ctrl+shift+enter`  and fill right to E9.

This would give a sum of 344 which is the same as F8

Comment: Hey, Ron thank you very much for the answer. Is there any way to formula something like this: within range B8:F8, if there is only one xx.5, round-down, if there is more than one xx.5, roundup the biggest xx.5 and round-down the other xx.5? ***this should correct the sum***

Comment: It is not clear to me how that would be "better", or even if it would work.  Especially since **none** of the values in your table are xx.5.  As a matter of fact, in your `105` line, **all** of the decimal values are well under `x.5`.  You can certainly set up formulas to compute pretty much what you want.  But be sure to understand what you are doing.

Comment: i guess i will have to manually do this. because what to round-up/round-down is based on xx.5 and the value.